# Fail to verify admin permission using function

Tags: php, html, mysql, post

I am makeing a sensitive page that no other user could access without being admin. But when i try to visit that page without being admin it works !

All users are not admin, So they should not be able to access it.

[image]

But the page loads fine for them (non admins).

PHP code:

```
function isAdmin(){

    $admin = mysql_query("SELECT `admin` FROM `users` WHERE `username` = '".$_SESSION['username']."'");

    if(!($admin)){


        echo 'You are not authorised';
        return false;

}else{
        return true;
}
}
```

The code on sensitive page:

```
if(isAdmin()){
        $name = $_POST['name'];
        $description = $_POST['description'];
        $image = $_POST['image'];
        $amount = $_POST['amount'];

        $sql = "INSERT INTO `store`(`name`, `description`, `price`, `image`) VALUES ('$name','$description','$amount','$image')";
        mysql_query($sql);



        echo 'Done!';

}
```

When i post data to this page , it loads and echoes `Done!` but it should not because:

- Current User is not an admin
- So, `isAdmin()` return false
- then `if(isAdmin())` receives `false`
- So the `if` statement should not execute.

Yes, I have all these:

- Mysql connection
- PHP server with correct `php.ini`
- Correct configuration my my `users` table
- The column `admin` in my Mysql `users` table is `int`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are basing your if condition on whether your query is syntactically correct or not. Since your query is valid, its always going to return something other than `false`.

use mysqli_num_rows instead.

```
if(msyql_num_rows($admin)<1)){


        echo 'You are not authorised';
        return false;

}else{
        return true;
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Take count instead of resource value. check below code

```
function isAdmin(){

        $admin = mysql_query("SELECT `admin` FROM `users` WHERE `username` = '".$_SESSION['username']."'");
        $count = mysql_num_rows($admin);

        if(!($count)){


            echo 'You are not authorised';
            return false;

    }else{
            return true;
    }

}
```